# For Loop with JSON data returns unexpected Identifier

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have the following JavaScript:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < e.blog.length; i++) {

    var id = e.blog[i].id;
    var date = e.blog[i].date;
    var title = e.blog[i].title;
    var image = e.blog[i].image;
    var excerpt = e.blog[i].excerpt;
    var tags = e.blog[i].tags;
    var html =
      'img src="' +
      image +
      '" alt="' +
      title +
      'image"<h1>' +
      title +
      "</h1>" +
      '<div class="post-details">' +
      '<span class="post-date">' +
      published +
      '<h2 class="post-title">' +
      title +
      "</h2>" +
      '<p class="post-excerpt">' +
      excerpt +
      "</p>" +
      '<div class="post-categories">' +
      '<span class="post-tag">' +
      tags +
      "</span>" +
      "</div> </div>";
    
          html = document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = html;
        }
      });
    
    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = html
```

Taking content from this JSON response:

```json
{
  ... (rest of json file before these dots important bit below)
  },
  "blog": {
    "post-1": {
      "id": "1",
      "date": "2020.08.01",
      "title": "Post Title",
      "excerpt": "Post excerpt goes here",
      "tags": "Post Tag 1, Post Tag 2",
      "body": "Blog body content goes in this field"
    },
    "post-2": {
      "id": "1",
      "date": "2020.08.01",
      "title": "Post Title",
      "excerpt": "Post excerpt goes here",
      "tags": "Post Tag 1, Post Tag 2",
      "body": "Blog body content goes in this field"
    }
  }
}
```

And it should be displaying the HTML from the JavaScript in the div with an id of `data` shown below

```html
    <div id='data'>
    </div>
```

However it returns the following error:

> Unexpected identifier 'I'

How would I go about fixing this? shouldn't it work due to I being specified at the start of the for loop?

Created an array out of the blog however all it does is return the following error. Code below the error:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object
> (evaluating 'e.blog[i].id')

JS

```js
    const arrBlog = Object.values(e.blog);
    console.log(arrBlog);
    for (var i = 0; i < arrBlog.length; i++) {
      var id = arrBlog[i].id;
      var date = arrBlog[i].date;
      var title = arrBlog[i].title;
      var image = arrBlog[i].image;
      var excerpt = arrBlog[i].excerpt;
      var tags = arrBlog[i].tags;
      var html = `
                  <div class="post">
            <img src="${image}" alt="${title} Image" />
            <div class="post-details">
                    <span class="post-date">${date}</span>
                    <h2 class="post-title">${title}</h2>
                    <p class="post-excerpt">${excerpt}</p>
                    <div class="post-categories">
                        <span class="post-tag">${tags}</span>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            `;
      html = document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `html i +=` should be `html +=`
2. `e.blog` is not an array, therefore `e.blog.length` is undefined. You can use a loop like this instead:
   `for (var i in e.blog)`
3. I've corrected your updated code:

> ```
> const arrBlog = Object.values(e.blog)
> for (var i = 0; i < arrBlog.length; i++) {
>     var published = "";
>     var document = "";
>     var id = arrBlog[i].id;
>     var date = arrBlog[i].date;
>     var title = arrBlog[i].title;
>     var image = arrBlog[i].image;
>     var excerpt = arrBlog[i].excerpt;
>     var tags = arrBlog[i].tags;
>     var html =
>         'img src="' +
>         image +
>         '" alt="' +
>         title +
>         'image"<h1>' +
>         title +
>         "</h1>" +
>         '<div class="post-details">' +
>         '<span class="post-date">' +
>         published +
>         '<h2 class="post-title">' +
>         title +
>         "</h2>" +
>         '<p class="post-excerpt">' +
>         excerpt +
>         "</p>" +
>         '<div class="post-categories">' +
>         '<span class="post-tag">' +
>         tags +
>         "</span>" +
>         "</div> </div>";
>     document.getElementById("data").innerHTML += html;
> }
> ```

Comment: Edited original post with an array constant. I receive an error now `Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.blog[i].id')`

Comment: This works for one post however the loop doesn't repeat and display the second post? Code updated

Comment: I've updated the answer again. Changed `.innerHTML = html` to `.innerHTML += html`

Answer (score 2):

On line 2 you are doing `html i += [...]`, which is not valid JavaScript. I think you mean `html += [...]` without the `i` there

Comment: This fixes the error however the posts still aren't being displayed in the div

Comment: Others are saying the `blog` is not an array. Could you look at their answers and see if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

`response.blog` is not an array. Try to get `Object.keys(response.blog)` and then iterate over them.

Check this example:

```js
const keys = Object.keys(response.blog);

keys.map(key => `<div attr="${response.blog[key].something}">...</div>`)
```

Comment: Is this different to a for loop? Or am I just running a for loop on an array instead of an object, I have done this before with an object and had it working

Comment: You can use result of Object.keys in for loop as well. map is just more compact way to iterate over array data.

Answer (score 0):

Your blog is an object not an array.

```
const arrBlog = Object.values(response.blog)
for(var i=0 ; i<arrblog.length ;i++ ){...
```

Comment: I turned blog into an array and now receive the following error `Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.blog[i].id')`

Comment: don't use `e.blog[i].id`, we have created separate array *arrBlog*. Can you try by using `arrBlog[i].id`?

Comment: updated using `arrBlog[I].id` I now receive this error `Unhandled Promise Rejection: ReferenceError: Cannot access uninitialized variable.`

Comment: can you post the line how are you initializing arrBlog?